# What is the difference between ContainerVisual.Offset and Visual.VisualOffset?

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

If you look at [the documentation for DrawingVisuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingvisual), you'll find two very similar-looking properties: `Offset` (inherited from ContainerVisual) and `VisualOffset` (from Visual). The descriptions of the properties are extremely similar and there is no further explanation on the docs. What is the difference between them? When should I be using which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick your favorite, as they are effectively the same

Here is the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationCore/R/25b212a8f6aed7eb.html),

**Given**

```
public class DrawingVisual : ContainerVisual
```

`ContainerVisual` implements `Offset` as such

```
public Vector Offset
{
    get
    {
        return base.VisualOffset;
    }
    set
    {
         base.VisualOffset = value;
    }
}
```